# R: Fixing For Loop Defined as Function

Tags: r

Using r, I want to run the below variable through the defined function:

```
bn<- .1

bcalc<- for i in 1:10{
  bn[i]<- (bn**i)
  return(bn[i])
}
```

How do I fix this to return all values for `bn[i]`?

Comment: Do you just want `bcalc <- .1**(1:10)`? No need for a for loop.

Comment: Though @MrFlick comment is right, *How do I fix this to return all values for bn[i]?* Simple, take the `return` out of the loop. Like this it will return the first time through the loop.

Comment: You confuse the concept of a function and a for loop

Comment: I want to see all values for bn raised to the power of i, for all values 1:10.